# How to get data from push notification response in ios by using Nativescript

Tags: apple-push-notifications, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

How to retrieve and handle the payload data from the app in background & foreground in `iOS`. I got the push notifications working, but I don't know how to extract the response.

```
notificationCallbackIOS: (message: any) => {
console.log("Message : " + JSON.stringify(message));
}

"nativescript-push-notifications": "^1.1.3"
```

This callback is not working. I am unable to extract the payload data like action, title.

Comment: I have this problem too, did you find something?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this plugin https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-local-notifications

it has a `addOnMessageReceivedCallback` event for listening for incoming notifications. I also used it on my app that i'm developing now. Even its for local notification, it also listens for remote notification you can call it on your `app.component.ts`.